# Low fps when rendering 146.735 squares (2x2) in sdl2?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I build a printer for one dimensional cellular automata, for which I use SDL_RenderFillRect()/ SDL_RenderFillRects() to print the cells.
The view allows certain zoom levels for a rule, the lowest zoom level (width of a square) will render 146.735 squares for Rule 30 (see screenshot), with each square having a dimension of 2x2 px (total px: 586.940 ).

However, the fps are not what I expected...

(Rule 30 at pixeldim 2x2)
[image: Rule 30 at pixeldim 2x2]

I first used SDL_RenderFillRect() in a loop which resulted in the following fps

Rendering Rule 30 using SDL_RenderFillRect():

| Zoom | fps |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 59 |
| 9 | 59 |
| 8 | 59 |
| 7 | 59 |
| 6 | 59 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 4 | 36 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 2 | 9 |

I then handed the data to SDL_RenderFillRects() which resulted in the following fps

Rendering Rule 30 using SDL_RenderFillRects():

| Zoom | fps |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 59 |
| 9 | 59 |
| 8 | 59 |
| 7 | 59 |
| 6 | 59 |
| 5 | 59 |
| 4 | 59 |
| 3 | 59 |
| 2 | 45 |

That is way better but I still don't understand how a simple task like that drops to anything below 60 on a modern office computer ??

**My question is:**
Is SDL_RenderFillRect()/ SDL_RenderFillRects() not the right thing for this usecase ?
What would be a more efficient approach ?

**Renderer** (uses vsync and hardware acceleration)

```
...
pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
...
```

**Using the Renderer for Table 1**

```
    // Render only the zoomed contents
    for (int i = 0; i < iZoomedCells; i++) {
        if (sCellMap[i].bActive) {
            SDL_RenderFillRect(pRenderer, &sCellMap[i].rCell);
        }
    }
```

**Using the Renderer for Table 2**

```
SDL_RenderFillRects(pRenderer, sCellRects, iZoomedCells);
```

Anything black is background and not a call to RenderFillRect().
Also: the more black space a rule has the higher the fps are.

Comment: It seems like the hardware accelerated `SDL_RenderFillRect` emits a draw call to the gpu for every invocation. This is very expensive. SDL Version 3 seems to have improved this: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/pull/4759
Alternatively you could just use e.g. OpenGL directly and use a VBO to submit all the Rectangles in a single draw call.

Comment: You shouldn't be drawing individual rects. Create a large surface/texture and modify the pixels directly, this should be faster.

Comment: I strongly suggest to work directly on the pixel array to improve performance of your program so that you could make a single draw call instead of one for square

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

My current solution boils down to this:

*(After a new ruleset is choosen)*

```
// Flush the old surface and texture

SDL_FillRect(pSurfaceMap, NULL, 0x000000);
SDL_DestroyTexture(pTextureMap);

// Draw determined rects of this rule to a surface

SDL_FillRects(pSurfaceMap, sCellRects, iCountRectsRendered, SDL_MapRGBA(pSurfaceMap->format, cDarkYellow.r, cDarkYellow.g, cDarkYellow.b, cDarkYellow.a));

// Create a texture from the surface

pTextureMap = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pSurfaceMap);
```

*(In the FrameDrawingFunction)*

```
SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, pTextureMap, NULL, NULL);
```

That approach will lead to stable 59 fps vsynced and 700+ fps unsynced.
That is already more like what I expected a simple rendering task's workload should cause.